# How to decimal validation : restricting only two Numeric values to be entered?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

there is a jsfiddle which restricts entering only two values after `dot` [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S9G8C/1/). I also need to restrict only two Numeric values before `dot` like i would like to have values like 55.66 etc.

how to do this in javascript? also allow `only Numbers to be entered before and after dot`

Comment: The use of a regular expression would probably be your best bet.

Comment: By "restrict", do you mean "allow only exactly two digits" or "only 1-2 digits" or "0-2 digits"? Should `1.2` be allowed? Or `.33` or simply `10`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need of `keypress` Instead use `onblur` and you could use the following regex

```
function validateFloatKeyPress(el, evt) {
    if (!/^\d\d\.\d\d$/.test(el.value)) {
        alert("Two digits before and after point please!");
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/S9G8C/199/)

Comment: `/^\d{0,2}\.\d\d$/` I think this regex might be want the OP wants, since they say they want only 2 numbers before the `dot`. Which implies that 1 number before the `dot` is ok.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keypress', function (event) {
    var value = event.target.value + String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    if (!(/^\d{1,2}(\.$|\.\d{1,2}$|$)/).test(value)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" />
```